# PHP MYSQLI-how to view the items from the table once

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to display the items from the database once using the description attribute of the files. For example i uploaded 3 files, automatically they have the same information except for the primary key.

```
if($type=="Title"){
$key = $_POST['search_key'];
    if($key!=null){ 
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT description  FROM __scannedfiles WHERE title='$key' AND  deptname='$dept_name'")  OR die(mysqli_error());
    $count =mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($count==0){
       echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.onload = function(){alert("File not found!")} </script>';
    } else if($count>0) {
        echo'<div class="searched_items_pane">
       <table class="table" width="100%" style="table-layout:fixed">
         <col width="20%">
        <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <th>  Title </th> 
        <th> Type </th>
        <th> Date </th>
        <th>  Description </th>
        </tr>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      echo'<tr>
        <td><a href="items.php?     desc='.urlencode($row[7]).'"onClick="MM_openBrWindow(\'items.php?desc='.urlencode($row[7]).'\',\'google\',\'width=650,height=500\'); return false;">
        <img src="Folder-Blank-icon.png"></a></td>          


 <td> '.$row[1].' </td>
        <td> '.$row[5].' </td>
        <td> '.$row[6].' </td>
        <td> '.$row[7].' </td>
         </tr>';
    }
    if($count>0){
      echo'</table> 
      </div>';
    }
}                               
}
  }
mysqli_close($con);     
 }
```

result:

```
     karla   Memo    2012-12-31  2131
     karla   Policy  2013-12-31  121212
     karla   Memo    2013-12-31  qweqw
     karla   Memo    2013-12-31  qweqw
```

here is the desired result:

```
     karla   Memo    2012-12-31  2131
     karla   Policy  2013-12-31  121212
     karla   Memo    2013-12-31  qweqw
```

Comment: *display the items from the database once* means?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without desired output and your table `__scannedfiles` structure but you can try using `DISTINCT`

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM __scannedfiles WHERE title='$key' AND  deptname='$dept_name'");
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53587/3)**

Comment: @user2335183, You may need to choose only required column in select query for getting distinct results. `SELECT DISTINCT col1, col5, col6, col7 from tablename`

Comment: i already did that but there is an error: Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given

Comment: @user2335183 Some fields that you pull from the table may make your rows unique. Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53587/3) based on your data

Comment: @user2335183 Post your exact code after change you've made. Preferably in your original question, not in comments.

Comment: @peterm i tried the code from sql fiddle, still nothing happened.

Comment: @user2335183 Can you recreate your problem with your real data in sqlfiddle (e.g. based on my sqlfiddle) and post `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table?